# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (SQL: select * from `gallery` where `status` = 1)

Tags: database, laravel, phpmyadmin

I'm working on laravel project and using cpanel phpmyadmin to store my database. When compiled, everything was fine. But it keeps show an error message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it. (SQL: select * from `gallery` where
>   `status` = 1)

And this is my .env looks like:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=iipexco_indonesia
DB_USERNAME=myusername
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

How to solve this case? Should I find the solution on phpmyadmin? What should I do? Fyi, I'm using an online server to store the database

Comment: You shouldn't leak confidential informations from your `.env` file, when you do such a thing, replace them before by random values

Comment: Try to put your DB password in quotes! If there are stranger chars or multiple words you must put it to quotes